# Counting how many times a pair of words appears together in a text file using R

Tags: r, string, equivalence

I have a function that takes in a document of text and two words that I want to find within that text, and I'm trying to figure out the probability that those 2 words appear next to each other in the text.
So the first thing I did is make them into pairs. My document is called "words" and the function takes 3 arguments: the document, word1 and word2. I want to figure out how many times they appear next to each other in the text.

```
pairs <- c()
  # Iterates through and creates every possible pair of adjacent words
  for (i in 1:(length(words)-1)) {
    temp <- paste(words[i],words[i+1], sep = ":") # Temporarily group adjacent words together with a : in between
    temp <- sort(strsplit(temp, ":")[[1]]) # Sort to get them lexically organized 
    pairs[i] <- paste(temp[1], temp[2], sep=":") # Store this pair in the list
  }
```

Now I'm trying to make a counter to figure out how many times my 2 specified words appear together. So far I have tried this

```
pairs2<-0
    for(i in pairs){
    if(i==word1:word2|i==word2:word1){
    pairs2<-pairs2+1
    }
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Error in word1:word2 : NA/NaN argument​
```

How do I get R to understand that I want each of these word1:word2 and word2:word1 pairs to be two specific words, and when I have the right combination, add a +1 to the counter?

Comment: Have you tried if(i==paste(word1, word2)|i==paste(word2, word1))?

Comment: Suggest you pose this question with a test dataset and if the data is in the form of multiple lines of data, then please indicate what you intend to happen if the word pairs have a line feed between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do. Given that you have a vector of words called `words`:

```
library(dplyr)

# use lead from dplyr to create all pairs of adjacent words
word.pairs <- paste(words, lead(words), sep=":")

# use dplyr to sum up all pairs of words
word.pairs <- as.data.frame(word.pairs) %>%
  group_by(word.pairs) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
```

This gives you a count of each word-pair in your vector. You can then use `dplyr`'s `filter()` and `arrange()` functions to sort the data or find the specific word-pair of interest. E.g., if you want to find the count of `word1` and `word2`

```
word.pairs %>% filter(word.pairs == paste(word1, word2, sep=":"))
```

Comment: thank you! Much quicker than what I was trying to do

Comment: Conventional wisdom is to avoid loops in R. If you do a quick Google search you can find plenty of detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the for loop for this if your document is broken into a list of word pairs.

For example, if you had a string like:

```
test <- "hello my name is my name is tony"
```

And your function broke it into a list of word pairs to make:

```
pairs <- list("hello my", "my name", "name is", "is my", "my name", "name is", "is tony")
```

You can get the number of times "my" and name appear together simply by:

```
appearance <- length(pairs[pairs == "my name"|pairs == "name my"]) # 2
```

Or in your case:

```
pairs2 <- length(pairs[pairs == paste(word1, word2) | pairs == paste(word2, word1)])
```